# Optimizing Neo4j query or graph model for finding sensor in a Building Hierarchy

Tags: charts, neo4j, query-optimization

I am working with a Neo4j graph that represents a building hierarchy, where buildings contain floors, rooms, and some rooms have subrooms. All nodes in the graph have the common label Resource and a unique uri property, which I have already indexed for faster lookup. Additionally, there are sensors (e.g., temperature sensors) represented as nodes labeled Temperature_Sensor, which can exist at various levels within the building hierarchy.

My objective is to efficiently retrieve all Temperature_Sensor nodes under a specific building node. I have crafted the following query for this purpose:

```
MATCH (:Resource {uri:"building_id_a"})-[*..15]->(c:brick__Temperature_Sensor)
RETURN c.uri
```

Here is the query profile:

[image]

However, this query appears to be quite expensive, as it searches through all nodes. While I understand I can reduce the relationship depth other than 15, this is just an example, and there could potentially be sensors at all levels. It would be ideal to utilize the indexed Resource and uri properties. In this case, we label the different types of equipment, such as Pump, Room, and Temperature Sensor, and use these labels to find all the Pump, Room, and Temperature_Sensor nodes.

I am aware that I could filter with different types of relationships as well, but we have used many different types and that could possibly indicate a modeling issue.

I am open to suggestions on potentially modeling the graph differently if it could lead to better query performance. Here is a picture of the Temperature_Sensor node for more context:

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any input you might have. Please feel free to share your thoughts or suggestions. Thank you! Also, I can provide more information if needed

Answer (score 1):

As you are only interested in which sensors are reachable from a given building node, you can add `DISTINCT` to the `RETURN` statement, and it will be planned with the much faster `VarLengthExpand(Pruning,BFS)` operator:

```cypher
MATCH (:Resource {uri:"building_id_a"})-[*..15]->(c:brick__Temperature_Sensor)
RETURN DISTINCT c.uri
```

If that isn't sufficient, then filtering on only the relevant relationship types should also improve performance:

```cypher
MATCH (:Resource {uri:"building_id_a"})-[:TYPE1|TYPE2|TYPE3 *..15]->
        (c:Pump|Room|Temperature_Sensor)
RETURN DISTINCT c.uri
```

Answer (score 1):

If this use case must be done as quickly as possible, you could neither:

1. Add a (redundant) `building_uri` property to your `brick__Temperature_Sensor` nodes, and create an index on that combination. Afterwards, this query would use that index and be very fast:

   ```
   MATCH (s:brick__Temperature_Sensor {building_uri: "building_id_a"})
   RETURN s.uri
   ```
2. Or, if you already have a [range index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes/search-performance-indexes/using-indexes/#range-indexes) (which is the default index type) or [text index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes/search-performance-indexes/using-indexes/#text-indexes) on the `uri` property of `brick__Temperature_Sensor` nodes, you can:

   - Change your sensor `uri` values from `<sensor_uri>` to something like `<building_uri>/<sensor_uri>`, and
   - Use the `STARTS WITH` operator (which will use the index):

     ```
     MATCH (s:brick__Temperature_Sensor)
     WHERE s.uri STARTS WITH "building_id_a"
     RETURN s.uri
     ```
   - Optionally, if you want to just get the <sensor_uri> returned, something like this would work:

     ```
     WITH "building_id_a" AS bId
     MATCH (s:brick__Temperature_Sensor)
     WHERE s.uri STARTS WITH bId
     RETURN SUBSTRING(s.uri, LENGTH(bId) + 1) as sensor_uri
     ```